# Tap into 4 wire RTD

Tags: temperature, rtd

Is there any way to tap into an existing 4 wire RTD without changing the resistance, and therefore changing the temp that the existing device will read?

Here's the scenario. The device is a medical refrigerator. It doesn't have an API I can use to get the temperature it's reading from a built in 4 wire RTD. I'd like to tap into the RTD with something like an Arduino to be able to read the temperature that way, but it seems like doing that will alter the resistance which will cause the temps to be off. Is there something I'm missing, or is this just not going to work?

Comment: Other than only tapping the sense lines?

Comment: I think that the answer is, probably not. I guess the RTD is connected to a measurement circuit, you cannot connect another one without conflicts with the measurement or even damaging the existing equipment. Unless the RTD is not connected to other equipment.

Comment: You guys making this over complicated. RTDs are 1k at most, many only 100 ohms. Even using a cmos op-amp may be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You could tap into the sense lines using a decent **[instrumentation amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier)**. The ground would have to be common between the two circuits so that the RTD stays within the common-mode range of the instrumentation amplifier.

You would be at the mercy of the energizing current supplied by the measuring instrument. If that current is constant, you'll get a reading proportional to resistance. If it's variable to linearize the RTD you'll get a reading more-or-less linear with temperature (with offset).

In particular, if the sensor you're trying to tap into is used with a controller, you should be careful not to cause any unforeseen issues with safety.

Eg. [INA826](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf):

[image]

Typically Pt100 RTDs have >200uA of energization current so the 35nA bias current will have little effect on the reading.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to tap into the sense circuit, but this is clearly much more invasive than your question is asking for. Potentially you can tap off add inputs somewhere, with a low enough load to not affect the original circuit.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that tapping into the existing RTD is going to allow retaining the existing device temperature accuracy. There are several possible reasons for this:

1. The existing sensor circuit may have a particular input impedance that acts in parallel with the RTD resistance. When you tap in you potentially add an additional parallel impedance that changes the net sensor impedance.
2. The existing sensor may very well have a linearization table built into its controller that converts the RTD reading to actual temperature reading. Simple tapping into the RTD bypasses this on the way to your parallel readout device.
3. The RTD device may be connected into some type of bridge circuit or temperature compensation circuit in the existing controller. A tapped in connection could upset the bridge or compensation circuitry.

I think you should really think about adding your own additional temperature probe device inside the unit and interface that to your logging device. You can get RTDs, PtResistance probes or even thermocouples.

Comment: RTDs are very low impedance, adding a parallel resistance in not a problem.   RTDs are very linear over the range this circuit has to work. No linearization required.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  The ground is isolated from RTD ground. [image]